# How to Search Numeric Text in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit

In my Project i have more than 4000 NUnit test cases and few of the test cases are hard coded with numeric text ex: 'string OperatorID="900457"' and the length of numeric text is more than 5, i tried using Visual Studio Search and Regular expression, nothing helped me out

If you have any clue then please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly have you tried, and why didn't it work? What do you want to do to the numbers (e.g. remove them)? A little more information would be helpful.

As far as I can tell, searching using the regex `[0-9]{5,}` should work for you. It will find series of digits that are at least 5 characters long.

**edit:** Because Visual Studio's Find and Replace function uses a different expression builder, used `"z:"`. This will find all integers that are surrounded by quotation marks. You can then use the "Bookmark All" option to mark all the lines in your tests that contain the hardcoded values.

Comment: I just want to find out those test cases which are hard coded with numeric text ex : "123456"

Comment: See my edit. I'm still a little unsure of what sort of output you are looking for.